# Q homeomorphic to Z?

Tags: general-topology

> Is $\mathbb{Q}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$?)
>   (Hint: Think of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\geq 1} \cup \{0\}$ and its image under any map in $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.)

I want to proceed the question by sequential criteria as given in the hint, but I am unable to make any progress.
Also $0$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{N}$, so I don't see what is meant by "under any map".
Please help with understanding and solving this question using sequential criteria.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you meant with "homeomorphic"?

Comment: What topology are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$, equipped with the subspace topology inherited from the usual topology on the real numbers, is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ (and therefore not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ either). Kavi Rama Murthy's answer gives a short and legible why this is the case. Here I give a proof that's in line with the hint given in the problem statement.

Consider the set $S = \left\{\frac{1}{n} \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. In the topology that $\mathbb{Q}$ inherits from $\mathbb{R}$, every open set containing $0$ contains some element of $S$.

Assume for a contradiction that we have a homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Then every open set containing $f(0)$ must contain an element of the form $f\!\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. But $\{ f(0) \}$ is a neighborhood of $f(0)$ in the topology that $\mathbb{N}$ inherits from $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $f\!\left(\frac{1}{m}\right) \in \left\{f(0)\right\}$, so $f\!\left(\frac{1}{m}\right) = f(0)$, contradicting the fact that homeomorphisms are bijective.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbb N,\ \mathbb Z$  and $\mathbb  Q$ are given the usual topologies then the first  two have discrete topology: every subset in them is open. But that is not true for the third one so the answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

A convergent sequence in ${\mathbb Z}$ is eventually constant. This is not the case of $f(\frac{1}{n})$ if $f: {\mathbb Q}\rightarrow {\mathbb Z}$ is one to one. As $\frac{1}{n}$ converges and $f(\frac{1}{n})$ does not, $f$ is not a homeomorphism.